# Update document with new userId after user authenticated for the second time

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following use case that is working as expected:

1. new user arrives on website
2. user is given an `user.uid` from anonymous sign in from firebase
3. user creates a document having as userId reference the aforementioned `user.uid`
4. in the very same page user is invited to sign in otherwise the document will be lost
5. user logs in and finds in is account the document

**WIN!**

Now I have a use case that is not working as expected:

1. returning user with session expired or from a different browser arrives on website
2. user is given an `user.uid` from anonymous sign in from firebase
3. user creates a document having as userId reference the aforementioned `user.uid`
4. in the very same page user is invited to sign in otherwise the document will be lost
5. user logs in and *doens't* find in is account the document

**DIDN'T WIN THIS TIME :(**

I configured firebase auth with the following configuration:

```
const uiConfig = {
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  autoUpgradeAnonymousUsers: true,
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
  callbacks: {
    signInFailure: (error: any) => {
      if (error.code != 'firebaseui/anonymous-upgrade-merge-conflict') {
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
      var cred = error.credential;
      return firebase.auth().SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred);
    }

  },
};
```

So, as you can see, the issue is that, the first time, `autoUpgradeAnonymousUsers` create a new userId with the anonymous user id and everything is fine, but of course the second time doesn't work anymore.

How should I solve this problem given that in my security rules I want to create a check that `userId` cannot be updated AND only a request with the same userId can see the document?

security rules:

```
allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId 
                    && request.auth.uid != null
allow update: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId && resource.data.userId == request.resource.data.userId && request.auth.uid != null
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you try to achieve in the second use case? Do you want to recover the document from the first use case, if the user does not create a permanent account?

Comment: No, not really. My original idea was not to lose the userId information before the first login. The second use case was an edge case I didn't think of.

Comment: Hm i do not see why this should not work. If you sign in anonymously you should always get a new uid. Could you reproduce the behavior? Could you show more of your code?

Comment: If you use the autoMerge functionality available when anonymous login is enabled, the first time the user authenticates, the anonymous uid will be used for the logged in user and they will be the same. If you logout and log in a second time then user id of course will change. Actually that’s the code needed to autoMerge anonymous into logged in user. What do you need specifically as additional code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can not create a new user with the same credentials. If the user logs in he looses the data from the anonymous sign in.

You have to save the data from the anonymous user locally and after the user logs in you have to copy the data to the current user. You should also deleting the anonymous account.

I have found this example which uses the Firebase realtime database to save the user data.

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#upgrading-anonymous-users

```
    // signInFailure callback must be provided to handle merge conflicts which
    // occur when an existing credential is linked to an anonymous user.
    signInFailure: function(error) {
      // For merge conflicts, the error.code will be
      // 'firebaseui/anonymous-upgrade-merge-conflict'.
      if (error.code != 'firebaseui/anonymous-upgrade-merge-conflict') {
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
      // The credential the user tried to sign in with.
      var cred = error.credential;
      // If using Firebase Realtime Database. The anonymous user data has to be
      // copied to the non-anonymous user.
      var app = firebase.app();
      // Save anonymous user data first.
      return app.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .once('value')
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            data = snapshot.val();
            // This will trigger onAuthStateChanged listener which
            // could trigger a redirect to another page.
            // Ensure the upgrade flow is not interrupted by that callback
            // and that this is given enough time to complete before
            // redirection.
            return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred);
          })
          .then(function(user) {
            // Original Anonymous Auth instance now has the new user.
            return app.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set(data);
          })
          .then(function() {
            // Delete anonymnous user.
            return anonymousUser.delete();
          }).then(function() {
            // Clear data in case a new user signs in, and the state change
            // triggers.
            data = null;
            // FirebaseUI will reset and the UI cleared when this promise
            // resolves.
            // signInSuccessWithAuthResult will not run. Successful sign-in
            // logic has to be run explicitly.
            window.location.assign('<url-to-redirect-to-on-success>');
          });

    }
```